# replace special characters in a text file batch

Tags: batch-file, replace, text-files, special-characters

Ouch. This one hurts. Hard to summarize my question as I'm thinking it's got many parts to it. Relevant and illustrative code section:

```
call %wabat%
set _tmpGameP_gF=%waoutput%
echo Result: %_tmpGameP_gF%
if not exist "%_tmpGameP_gF%" (
        echo That is an invalid file path or filename! Folder or file does not exist. Please re-select or re-enter.  
        exit /b
        )
FOR %%i IN ("%_tmpGameP_gF%") DO (
        set _tmpbarefile=%%~ni
        set _tmpfilepath=%%~dpi
        set _tmpfilename=%%~nxi
    )
```

wabat.bat is just a text file generated by Wizapp.exe, containing something like and in its entirety:

```
set waoutput=I:\Tests\Somefile(North)[!].zip
set waoutnum=
```

Idea of script: part1 tests to see if the file exists and part two splits file into constituent parts.

Problem is, of course, the special characters. This works fine until you get special chars into the mix.

Whilst the command line reads:

```
set waoutput=I:\Tests\Somefile(North)[!].zip
```

(this is from the Call)

When echo the result (even if try echoing %waoutput%) I get:

```
Result: I:\Tests\Somefile(North)[].zip
```

Obviously this is to do with the parsing of the !.

Tried lots of things, just can't get this working - I have a feeling this one's an incredibly difficult bridge to cross.

Oh, and just to make it immense fun, I can't rename the files or folders. It would be OK to alter the wabat.bat file. Thought about search and replace of wabat.bat for all special characters to add escape characters, but got totally lost trying to do this + not sure how useable this would be in final use of variable etc.

Would really appreciate any help on this one as 7,000 lines in and hit a brick wall!
Thanks for any replies...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you have the Delayed expansion enabled.

Try this to anderstand :

```
@echo off
set waoutput=I:\Tests\Somefile(North)[!].zip
echo %waoutput%

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo %waoutput%
```

--> output :

```
I:\Tests\Somefile(North)[!].zip
I:\Tests\Somefile(North)[].zip
```

You have to disable the enabledexpansion when working on your files if they can contain the `!` char

Answer (score 0):

Disable delayed expansion should be enough.

```
Setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
```

Use it before calling your wabat and call it without the percent signs.